# react native firebase error

Tags: firebase, react-native

estoy tratando de instalar firebase en mi proyecto, ya lo instalé y estoy tratando de ejecutar la aplicación pero me sale este error:

```
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
C:\Users\oscar\Desktop\notificaciones\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\android\src\reactnative\java\io\invertase\firebase\app\ReactNativeFirebaseAppInitProvider.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".reactnativefirebaseappinitprovider";
               ^
  symbol:   variable APPLICATION_ID
  location: class BuildConfig
Note: C:\Users\oscar\Desktop\notificaciones\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\android\src\reactnative\java\io\invertase\firebase\utils\ReactNativeFirebaseUtilsModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':@react-native-firebase_app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

Muchas gracias